# Include a table in each div that appends body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing a web-site where i will need to get some json data for some places that will include images, titles, information etc and i need to present them to a website.

I have developed a prototype where i user the HTML5 classic template and i successfully appended my `"article"` with 10 `<div>Example div</div>` divs using a `for` statement and i am able to give them a unique id using the counter `i`.

My code for this is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

for (var i=1; i<10; i++){

$("article").append("<div id=myid"+i+">Example div</div");

}

    });
</script>
```

This works great but the thing is that i want to append the `article` using seperate divs with unique ids and will each include a table that will be filled with the json data i will recieve in the future.

But when i try to write my code and place inside the div tags the below code i get a syntax error...

```
 <table width="597" border="1"><tr><td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td><td rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
```

Any thougts?

Comment: Consider a JS-based templating system, such as: http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/tutorial-html-templates-with-mustache-js/

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle which replicates the problem? :?

Comment: Could the syntax error be you are using quotes inside of a quoted string without escaping it? \"

Comment: also this might be a way: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/

Comment: You seem to be missing some quotes in the HTML you append in your for loop. You have no quotes around your id value; you should probably amend that line so it reads: `$("article").append("<div id='myid"+i+"'>Example div</div");`. Regardless of whether or not it's causing your problem, you should still fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it together the correct way was to add:

```
$("article").append("<table id="+i+" width="+597+" border="+1+"><tr><td rowspan="+2+">&nbsp;</td><td rowspan="+3+">&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>");
```

i just ad to add "+the numeric value for the table content+" and that way it works thanks all for the comments and suggestions! :)